# Use global variables as parameters of a function allocated in other source file

Tags: c++, arrays, global-variables

I'm coding a program of openGL which read the points and the faces from a text file and later displays them on the screen.

I do the opengl matters in main.cpp and I load the file in LoadFile.cpp.

In the main, I have an array with the points that I'm going to display:

```
   Point3f* vertexContainer;
   int vertexn;
```

And I've declared the function that I'm going to use in order to load the source file:

```
extern void loadFile(const char*,Point3f*, int, Face*, int);
```

*Note that extern is not mandatory here. Don't care about faces, for the momment.*

Inside LoadFile.cpp:

```
void loadFile(const char* path, Point3f* vertexContainer, int nvertex,
        Face* faceContainer, int nfaces)
{
//reading and processing source file,
//storing the input vertices in: std::vector<Point3f> verticesVector.

//Finally:
    vertexContainer = &verticesVector[0];
    vertexn = verticesVector.size();
}
```

And nothing is displayed on the screen. Also, If I debug vertexContainer, I realize that its value never changes.

However, if I debug a local variable vc, I can see the changes:

```
Point3f* vc = &verticesVector[0];
```

I have noticed that, if i pass by reference the array, it changes, but, mysteriously when the program control comes back to main, its values have changed wrongly!
 And I had thought that arrays never have to be passed by reference.

The other approach is return the vector itself to the main, but prefer be able to work with arrays, once the file is processed.

Comment: I've just tried to return vector<Point3f> by reference and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration

```
extern void loadFile(const char*,Point3f*&, int, Face*, int);
```

is incompatible with the definition

void loadFile(const char* path, Point3f* vertexContainer, int nvertex,
        Face* faceContainer, int nfaces)
{

And

```
vertexContainer = &verticesVector[0];
vertexn = &verticesVector.size();
```

update the function's copies of what the caller put as arguments

also, `&verticesVector[0]` will be destroyed at scope end of `loadFile` with the destruction of `verticesVector`.

Comment: Yes, there are two inconsistencies there but they're not actually in my code.I'm fixing them in the question, sorry.

So, do i need to copy the vector into an array? isn't there a better way to avoid a operation of O(n) cost, like taking a reference to the contents of the vector??

Comment: You can return the vector.

Answer (score 0):

`verticesVector` will be destroyed at the end of scope `loadFile`

You can try to use `vector<PointF>` instead of `vertexContainer` and `vertexn` and write data directly into `vertexContainer`